# Finding sound track webportals for product animations?

Tags: animation, audio, product

I'm looking for a sound track webportal which helps me FASTER finding matching soundtracks for product animation videos. Unfortunately I'm loosing a lot of time with this working step. Either I'm using the wrong search criterias (mood, genre, instruments, bpm,...) or inappropriate webportals. Right now I tried Soundstripe, Artlist,...

Maybe someone has a tip?
Thanks...